# CSS Gradient very rough in Chromium

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, chromium, linear-gradients

I have a linear gradient as background, which works fine in Firefox, Opera classic etc. but jumps in 10px strips in Chromium (and also on Android stock browser). You can see there is no smooth gradient but 2 stripes instead.

My problem is also that I want a sharp cut (blue/white) but because of the 10px strips the cut jumps in 10px steps instead of 1px. I have the blue box here which should be aligned with the gradient but doesn't because of these 10px steps.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0px,#247), color-stop(800px,#247), color-stop(800px,#fff), color-stop(820px,#fff), color-stop(820px,#247), color-stop(1000px,#247)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #247 0px,#247 800px,#fff 800px,#fff 820px,#247 820px,#247 1000px); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #247 0px, #247 800px, #fff 800px, #fff 820px,#247 820px, #247 1000px); /* W3C */
```

I'm also using all other prefixed versions (-moz, -o, -ms).

[image: Rough gradient in chromium]

**EDIT:** Ok, I should have added a demo to begin with, here it is: [Codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KcxFH). The left blue block should be exactly 1000px, as wide as the control block below. And it is in Firefox and Opera Classic, but not in Chrome and Chromium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an "optimisation feature" of chrome - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627292/) for more info. As of Chrome 35 you cannot rely on the width of columns created by gradient colour stops.

See [this pen](http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/fCsay) for a cool animated demonstration and links to bug (which are all in the other SO question too).

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just use a gradient generator ?

1. http://gradients.glrzad.com/
2. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

even from microsoft http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/

Comment: to clarify: my problem is not how to write or generate css gradient code but how Chromium displays it and what is going wrong here

Comment: can you please provide infos about you chromium version and os ? mac or linux

Comment: Chromium 28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.12.04.1 under Linux and Chrome 27.0.1453.116m under Windows XP